# Implement the waiting code more easily or more compactly in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

i wrote a code that works exactly the way i imagine it to. I just wonder if the whole thing is easier and can be done with less code? In principle I am satisfied, but my feeling tells me that it has to be easier ?!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var counter = 0
    @State private var wait = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.counter)")
            Text("\(self.wait)")
                .onReceive(timer) { time in
                    if self.counter == 10 {
                        self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    } else if self.counter == 1 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting"
                    } else if self.counter == 2 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting."
                    } else if self.counter == 3 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting.."
                    } else if self.counter == 4 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting..."
                    } else if self.counter == 5 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting"
                    } else if self.counter == 6 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting."
                    } else if self.counter == 7 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting.."
                    } else if self.counter == 8 {
                        self.wait = "Waiting..."
                    } else if self.counter == 9 {
                        self.wait = ""
                    }
                    self.counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a range, we can display our wait message. It may be useful to cancel the timer if greater than 9. Inside the 1 to 8 range use repeating characters with the module operator to get the desired message.

```
if 1...8 ~= self.counter { 
  self.wait = "Waiting" + String(repeating: ".", count: (self.counter-1)%4)
} else if self.counter == 9  {
  self.wait = ""
} else if self.counter == 10 {
  self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
}

self.counter += 1
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the input. It looks much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Have fun!
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

```
switch some value to consider {
case value 1:
    respond to value 1
case value 2,
     value 3:
    respond to value 2 or 3
default:
    otherwise, do something else
}
```